# Latexmk using right quotes

Tags: latexmk

I see in `Latexmk` documentation, that `-e` option is used for a way of giving initialisation code directly on latexmk’s command line. I know, that  the  single  quotes  block normal UNIX/LINUX command shells from treating the characters inside the  quotes  as  special.

I try this command under MS-Windows:

```
latexmk -pvc -pdfxe -time -e "$pdflatex='xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error'" -e "$pdf_previewer = 'start \"c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" %O %S'" my_file.tex
```

specially, I have a problem with second part of the command above:

```
-e "$pdf_previewer = 'start \"c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" %O %S'"
```

Where should be used single and double quotes?

I have this error message:

```
Latexmk: Stopping because executing following code from command line
    $pdf_previewer = 'start c:/Program
gave an error:
    Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at (eval 11) line 1.
```

Comment: Don't know nothing about MS-DOS, but latexmk is perl. I am not sure that %0 and %S will be expanded inside simple quote. Anyway, the issue is somewhere else : maybe since you escape the first ", you should also escape the closing one (or escape none. I would try without \, since I can't see why you escaped it). The message error is related to ' but it might help.